# Apache/NodeJS local ServerAlias css/js 404

Tags: node.js, apache

so I’ve got everything working (Apache/NodeJS/framework7) locally only I wanted to access my app within my own network via 192.168.x.x.
I set up access via Apache ServerAlias and it does let me see the app on desktop.

I only get this error when accessing via IP on mobile. (Also on desktop)

GET http://192.168.2.21/packages/core/css/framework7.bundle.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://192.168.2.21/packages/core/js/framework7.bundle.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I guess it is somehow looking in the wrong folder? But I am not sure why, I don’t really have much experience with node.

For some reason it also fails to load a font in a css file, but I am also loading images from /img in the same css file and they work fine?
GET http://192.168.2.21/fonts/exo/Exo-Regular.tff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So http://localhost:3000/node-app/ works.
But http://192.168.2.21/ doesn't work, does show the page but no css/js loaded.

Thing is I need to test my app on mobile because it has some mobile-only features, so I have to be able to reach it from the outside.

I have already tried changing some configurations in both Apache and NodeJS but nothing seems to make a difference.

Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   ServerName test.local
   ServerAlias 192.168.2.21

   DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\test\test-app"
   <Directory />
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
   </Directory>

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   <Location 192.168.2.21>
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
   </Location>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Gulpfile

```
  connect.server({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    root: ['./'],
    livereload: false,
    port: '3000',
  });
```

Folders (not all of it)

```
test-app
 - css
 - js
node_modules
packages
 - core
scripts
src
gulpfile.js
package.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright turns out I was sort of staring blind on wanting to use Apache for this.
My solution right now is just to not use Apache at all.

```
  connect.server({
    host: '192.168.2.21',
    root: ['./'],
    livereload: false,
    port: '80',
  });
```

And then I created an index.html in the root that redirect to my app folder.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/my-app" />
```

Also note that changing root to ./my-app won't work as I have the packages/src folder in the root folder. This will create the same situation as before.